# (Python) Exception for wrong module being imported

Tags: python, regex, module, alias, python-re

In my python code, I need regex that matches from right to left. This is not supported in the standard regex (re) module, so instead, I'm using the [third-party `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/). This module allows me to split from right to left using its `REVERSE` flag:

```
regex.split(sub, s, 1, flags=re.REVERSE)
```

This flag does not work in the standard `re` module.

For convenience, I want it to still be called `re', since I use it in exactly the same manner (except for the case above). I achieve this using an alias:

```
import regex as re
```

My problem is that I want to make sure my functions use the correct regex module. My way to do this is by checking if `REVERSE` is a member of `re`:

```
    try:
        re.REVERSE
    except NameError:
        #What should I raise here?
```

My problem is that I do not know what exception to raise. I'm leaning towards an ImportError, but I'm not sure what is best. Or maybe everything I'm doing is wrong, and aliasing regex as re is bad practice in the first place. I'm not sure.

Thanks for reading!

Bump - I got 2 opinions, which is great, but I don't think that's enough input to make the best decision - especially as the 2 opinions are completely different.

Comment: I lean toward importing it as `regex` to avoid confusion.  That makes it hard to accidentally import the wrong module, and it makes it obvious to others reading your code that it’s not the built in version.

Comment: @Samwise If it's bad practice, I'll remove the alias. However, I like having it called "re" because I'm used to typing "re", so it's more comfortable and less error-prone. In addition, I commonly use `regex` for variable / parameter names. In most cases, this is the most appropriate name I can think of - so it's nice to have it unreserved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for `AssertionError` - you are asserting a must-have condition of the module. You can raise it like your ImportError example or write a one-liner

```
assert hasattr(re, 'REVERSE'), 'Expected `import regex as re` to replace std re module'
```